# Agregar resultado a lista con append()

Tags: python-3.x, lista, beautifulsoup, scraping

Tengo este programa, el cual **carga un archivo de texto que contiene el código fuente** de [esta página](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Steel_Helmet) y mediante `BeautifulSoup4` raspo la columna `Npc` para obtener la lista de nombres.

Esta es la lista:

[image: Lista con los nombres a raspar]

Y este es el código fuente de mi programa:

```
import bs4 as bs

archivo = open('Steel_Helmet.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
mostrar = archivo.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(mostrar,'html5lib')

# -----------------------------------------------------
# NPCs Buy
# ---------------------------------------------------
# NOMBRE
table = soup.find('table', class_='sortable')
tbr = table.find_all('span', class_='tooltip')
nombreNpc=[]
for i in tbr:
    x = i.find('a').text
    nombreNpc.append(x)
    print(nombreNpc)
```

Básicamente encuentro la tabla, ubico la columna y por medio de un bucle `for` encuentro todos los tags `<a></a>` y obtengo el `.text` de cada uno de ellos, luego almaceno todos esos nombres en una lista por medio de la función `append()`, pero al parece estoy haciendo algo mal, ya que me arroja este resultado:

[image: Resultado]

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Solo quiero obtener una lista con todos los nombres, pero de manera uniforme, no así como la que mi programa arroja, ya que quiero acceder a cada nombre por medio de su indice.

Gracias!!

Comment: La lista es la esperada y creo que lo que buscas, simplemente imprimes en cada iteración del for la lista, imprimela una vez terminado el for.

Comment: @FJSevillasiempre estuve iterando dentro del bucle for, como no lo vi antes... super agradecido contigo por hacérmelo notar.

Comment: De nada, pasa más a menudo de lo que parece... :) Por cierto, puedes usar una lista por compresión que en éste caso además de más eficiente es incluso más simple: `nombreNpc = [i.find('a').text for i in tbr]`. Saludos.

Comment: Efectivamente, voy a probar la lista por compresión =D